# How can I declare the Type of a Variable in a Julia Object?

Tags: object, types, julia, declaration

How can I declare a parsimonious type of a variable in the constructor for a object in Julia ? As an example, consider the following:

```
type DetermineType
  foobar::Base.Prod2{LinSpace{Float64},LinSpace{Float64}}
end

function DetermineType(;foo = linspace(0, 1, 10),
                bar = linspace(0, 1, 10))
  foobar = Base.product(foo, bar)
  return DetermineType(foobar)
end
```

The declaration for `foobar` is`Base.Prod2{LinSpace{Float64},LinSpace{Float64}}`. I decided to use this type as it is the output of`typeof(foobar)`. Whilst this declaration is not yet too long, `Base.product` with more than two `Linspace` objects quickly become very verbose. After going through Julia's documentation about [Types](https://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/types/) I think I'm looking for the `supertype` of `foobar`. However, I don't know how to obtain it. Can somebody help?

Comment: Why not just parameterize it without a restriction?

Comment: Restricting parameter types is usually good when trying to give a specifically performant version for certain types. Using named parameters can currently (ver 0.5/0.6) introduce performance "challenges", so perhaps better to avoid in hot code

Comment: Just quickly to parameterize it without restriction in a type would be written: `type DetermineType{T} foobar::T end`

Comment: @LyndonWhite Can you briefly outline what ``{T}`` means? I've seen it multiple times in [Constructors](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/constructors/) but do not understand it's meaning.

Comment: Not as a comment no.
Create another question on stackoverflow, and I'm sure you'll get a good answer. (if one doesn't already exist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Supertype can be accessed via `supertype`. In this case, `supertype(typeof(foobar))` is a `Base.Iterators.AbstractProdIterator`.
2. How much you need to specialize depends on how specialized you need your functionality to be. You can easily end up specializing the type too much. In this case you could perhaps omit the type parameters and just have `foobar::Base.Iterators.Prod2`.
3. I'm not sure why the full type is not pretty - it is a very succinct way of describing the type requirement, IF you require the type to be so restricted.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! Your are right, ``Base.Prod2{LinSpace{Float64},LinSpace{Float64}}`` is not necessarily not pretty. I edited the original question accordingly.

Comment: @fabian I hate to be the bearer of bad news, but in Julia 7 this has actually expanded quite significantly :p. `typeof(Base.product(linspace(0,1,10), linspace(0,1,10)))` is now 
`Base.Iterators.Prod2{StepRangeLen{Float64,Base.TwicePrecision{Float64},Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}},StepRangeLen{Float64,Base.TwicePrecision{Float64},Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}}}`.

Comment: Having said that, you could always "alias" this and use the alias in your type definition: `const LinProd = Base.Iterators.Prod2{StepRangeLen{Float64,Base.TwicePrecision{Float64},Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}},StepRangeLen{Float64,Base.TwicePrecision{Float64},Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}}}`   (alas, however, when the object is _instantiated_, the full type will show, not the alias).